# Subclassing QAbstractTableModel for a large dataset via HTML/Ajax?

Tags: ajax, qt, dataset, qtableview

I'm trying to display a large table (a playlist with title, composer, etc... so I can't use a QListWidget) via QTableView with a sub-class of QAbstractTableModel. The call you have to override retrieving the data looks like this:

```
QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
```

This functions is called everytime for every cell (specified by index.row() & index.colum()). Translating that 1:1 to a HTML/Ajax would even kill performance with a local network.

So what are my options here? This must be possible because QSqlQueryModel exists and they must have the same problem. Googling for a combination of Ajax/QAbstractTableModel returned nothing at all.

Any ideas?

PS: To semi-answer myself, looking at the QT-Sources `src/sql/models/qsqlquerymodel.cpp` reveals the answer. It's possible but I'm wondering if someone knows a of-out-the-box solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short yes you will want to utilize the concepts you have learned by looking at the source for `QSqlQueryModel` or some derivative. It can be thought that in the example the `d` is really the true model storage containing the data (in their case it contains the SQL query with the data and indexes for determining if a fetches has to occur) and the `QSqlQueryModel` is just acting as a proxy class on top of it for integration with Qt's Model/View concept.

We have a similar situation here at the office where querying for the data cell by cell would introduce large inefficiencies. Therefore we created a class that efficiently handles all the requests across the network and abstracts it away. Then we use a pretty simple `QAbstractTableModel`-derived class to interact with the true model class to provide the data as Qt requires it. It works very well.

Just ensure that as you receive or remove data that you are properly manipulating the model data between `beginInsertRows`/`endInsertRows` and `beginRemoveRows`/`endRemoveRows` respectively.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me into the right direction. And for the bonus tip but it's a read only table.